# Accessing an image taken from another class

Tags: android, image, class, accessibility, declaration

I have a simple concept question.  I have a class that snaps a picture and displays it on a new java class: Result.java that displays the image on a basic ImageView in an xml file.

I assume the camera stores the saved image on the SD card.  Is there a way for a new Java class to access that photo that was taken and do stuff do it?  How do I go about calling that bmp in another class in my app?

Also, when the app is closed, is there a command for me to delete that picture taken?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure its a file..the hardware camera is sending a frame to the software buffer and that is the bits that get converted displayed by your class that snaps the picture.

Unless you have saved the file I do not think its saved anywhere..

Comment: Do you know how I could go about accessing the name of that file?